# How to avoid fragment duplication issue?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle, fragmentmanager

I have the following code:

```
private List<WeakReference<Fragment>> mFragList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>>();

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    mFragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}

public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for(WeakReference<Fragment> ref : mFragList) {
        Fragment f = ref.get();
        if(f != null) {
            if(f.isVisible()) {
                ret.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public Fragment findFragement(String tClass) {

    List<Fragment> fragments = getActiveFragments();
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        if (tClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Home")) {
            if (fragment instanceof ToggleFragment) {
                return fragment;

            }
        } else if (tClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Contacts")) {
            if (fragment instanceof ContactFragment) {
                return fragment;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The code works fine, but I have a concern, wouldn't this code:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    mFragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}
```

cause duplicates when a screen is recreated or ft.replace() is used?

Is there a better way around this ? without replacing much code or without using getsupportfragmentmanager.getfragments() ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to guarantee that there aren't duplicates is to use a map. You could add this line to the top of your class

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFragmentClassName";
```

Then, instead of using an `ArrayList`, you can use

```
Map<String, WeakReference<Fragment>> fragmentMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and add fragments to the map with

```
map.put(TAG, myWeakReferenceInstance);
```

When you want to add items, you can check if something is in that spot already by checking

```
if (map.get(TAG) != null) {
    //do something
}
```

This should work for you, but I still have to recommend using `getSupportFragmentManager()`. You can do all of this and more with it. For example, this is some code I've been using in this music app I've been building:

```
private void showAlbumListFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    albumListFragment = new AlbumListFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, albumListFragment, AlbumListFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
}
```

If you wanted to avoid duplication, you could just add a few lines:

```
private void showAlbumListFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    albumListFragment = (AlbumListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AlbumListFragment.TAG);
    if (albumListFragment == null) {
        albumListFragment = new AlbumListFragment();
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, albumListFragment, AlbumListFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
    }
```

Comment: is there no other way I can ensure duplication doesnt happen? can you explain with respect to my code if possible, would be easier to understand. not very good at hashmap

Comment: The easiest way I can think of without using a fragmentManager is to make some unique attribute (probably a String) that is constant for every instance of your fragment, and different for every type of fragment (I like to call mine "TAG"). Then, you can iterate through your ArrayList and check if any of your fragments have the TAG of the fragment you're trying to put in there, and if they do, replace them.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't use a fragmentManager? This is exactly what they are designed to handle.

Comment: I try to avoid supportmanager since its deprecated and can cause compile time issues

Comment: You should use FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag) to find fragments, not getFragments(). I'll edit my answer to show a clearer example on how to use it.

Comment: its all in an activity class. can i use the tag with List<Fragment> fragments  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151645/discussion-between-evanklicker-and-marissa-nicholas).

Comment: let me know if you got my last messages?